# About an application of maximum principle for viscosity solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, maximum-principle, viscosity-solutions

I am reading by myself [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2770980_Aleksandrov_reflection_and_geometric_evolution_of_hypersurfaces) paper and in the proof of the Theorem $6$ (it is on the page $7$), the authors stated

> Thus, by the maximum principle for viscosity solutions, the solution $u_t$ to the geometric level set flow satisfies $u_t(x) \geq u_t(x^*)$ for all $x \in H_-^{\lambda}(\nu)$ and $t \geq 0$.

I looked for this maximum principle on the references of this paper and the best that I could find is the famous works by Evans and Spruck and Chen, Giga and Goto. Both works has

> R. Jensen, The maximum principle for viscosity solutions of fully nonlinear second-order
> partial differential equations, Arch. Rational Mech. Anal. **101** (1988) 1-27.

as a reference, then I believe that the Theorem $3.1$ on page $16$ of [Jensen's paper](http://www.math.jhu.edu/%7Ejs/Math745/jensen.max.pdf) is the maximum principle that I am looking for. What I would like to know is how exactly apply this maximum principle to the Theorem $6$ of the paper that I am reading. I do not have knowledge of the techniques applied to study viscosity solutions and the method of sup and sub solutions, then I will appreciate if you can explain with details how this maximum principle imply the statement in the proof of the Theorem $6$ above because I could not to see immediately it.

Thanks in advance!